# jQuery 1.9.1 $('#idCheckbox:checked') IE7 and IE8 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and i have this code working fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome. The trouble is that i need it in IE7 and IE8 too, but doesn't work.

I have an input checkbox that use `id="selec"` and `name="selec"` 
the user can select many checkbox and then pass them to a javascript function.
IE7 and IE8 console doesn't show any error, just doesn't work.

I've been looking many solutions but no one works for me. I think the problem is in the line:

```
$('#selec:checked').each(function()...
```

because this line gather the selected options and then push them inside of the array named `"selectedItems"`

This is my javascript function:

```
function enviaMailNominaFiltrada() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedItems = new Array();

        $('#selec:checked').each(function () {
            selectedItems.push($(this).val());
        });

        var seleccionados = '<cfoutput>#todosSeleccionados#</cfoutput>' + ',' + selectedItems;
        var selecLargo = seleccionados.length;

        if (seleccionados.substring(selecLargo - 1) == ',') {
            var selecFiltrado = seleccionados.substring(0, seleccionados.length - 1);
        }
        else {
            var selecFiltrado = seleccionados;
        }

        if (selectedItems != '' || selecFiltrado != '0') {
            var info = "selectedItems=" + selectedItems;
            document.getElementById('lista2').value = selecFiltrado;
            document.enviarMail.action = 'enviarpostulantes.cfm';
            document.enviarMail.submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('Debe seleccionar al menos un registro para enviar nómina');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might have duplicate ID's which is invalid.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Please post your HTML for clarification.

Comment: @KevinB So now chrome/firefox/IE9 work with duplicate IDs?

Comment: @roasted: It's quite possible that they are more tolerant in this ...

Comment: Yes and no. They work, but it's still invalid and can lead to bugs. Different versions of IE use different paths to selecting elements. In modern browsers, selectors like this are passed directly to document.querySelectorAll() which will select duplicate ID's.

Comment: @user2390538: use the "class" attribute instead of "id" for multiple elements

Comment: @KevinB Really interesting, thx!

Comment: Note, even though IE8 comes with document.querySelectorAll(), IE8 doesn't use it in this case because IE8 doesn't support :checked, therefore in IE7 and 8, document.getElementByID() is used to get the first element with said id, that element is then filtered to only ones with the checked property set to true.

Comment: @KevinB: Of course I am aware that it is wrong even if it works - after all, if something is called ID, it is usually supposed to be unique ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line :

```
$('#selec:checked').each(function () {
```

indicates to me that your using multiple DOM elements with the same id (`selec`) - this will be the cause of your problems.

If DOM elements have an `id` attribute specified - that value must be unique against all other DOM elements on the same document

use a class ...

```
<select class="myclass">
...
</select>

$('.selec:checked').each(function () {
```

Comment: well, they don't ALL have to have unique id's, but when one does have an id, the id must be unique. `:)`

Comment: @KevinB perhaps that statement is a little misleading ... i meant that if they have an id it must be unique ... i will change it .. Thanks

Comment: "I don't always need an id, but when I do, it better be unique" - Dom Element

Comment: you guys rock... i just put a `class="Chequeados"` into my input checkbox and then i changed the `$('#selec:checked').each(function(){...`  for `$('.Chequeados:checked').each(function(){... `
and now works fine in IE7 and IE8. Thank you very VERY much.